# kqueues on Mac OS X: strange event order

Tags: macos, vim, bsd, kqueue, hfs

I monitor a file for changes in a separate thread using kqueues/ kevent(2).
(I monitor a Python file for reparsing)

I subscribe as following:

```
EV_SET(&file_change, pyFileP, EVFILT_VNODE,
       EV_ADD | EV_CLEAR,
       NOTE_DELETE |  NOTE_WRITE | NOTE_EXTEND | 
               NOTE_ATTRIB | NOTE_LINK | NOTE_RENAME | NOTE_REVOKE,
       0, 0);
```

When I write to the file "/tmp/somefile.py" using Vim, I get two separate kevents:
The flags of these events (event.fflags) are:

```
NOTE_RENAME
```

and

```
NOTE_DELETE | NOTE_LINK
```

I never get a "NOTE_WRITE" event! 
This seems to have something to do with the way Vim writes these files, since if I do

```
echo "sometext" >> /tmp/somefile.py
```

I do get the:

```
NOTE_WRITE|NOTE_EXTEND
```

event.

Odd, eh? I haven't checked the Vim source code but it must do something strange, or does it simply use user level functions that are implemented that way?

I wasn't really expecting this. Is this a known problem, I just have to check for all events possible, or is there a known interface that really checks if a file has been written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is actually happening is that Vim won't write over the same file, first
it probably renames it to something else and then creates another file (link).
You can confirm that by doing something like:

```
$ vim file -c wq
```

This will open a file and write it. Now check the inode:

```
$ ls -i
30621217 file
```

Write the file with Vim again and re-check the inode:

```
$ vim file -c wq
$ ls -i
30621226 file
```

It's just different. That means the second file is actually another file
(linked to another inode) with the same name, and the old one was unlinked.

Many editors do that. I can't confirm why exactly Vim takes this approach.
**Maybe** for safety: if you first rename the file and something goes wrong
while writing the new file, you still have the old one. If you start writing
over a file and a problem occurs (even with memory) you'll probably loose part
of it. **Maybe**.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. This is a bit problematic though.

Comment: Indeed. But do you have to listen to all events? You could register for NOTE_WRITE | NOTE_LINK and both cases (real append, like echo from the shell, or a new file) should work.

Comment: Yes I guess that set of events would be safe. Thanks for the help.